# Sometimes reloading page, sometimes deleting from cart

Tags: jquery

I am working on a shopping cart of sorts. Have got it all set up that items can be added to cart (multiple items can be handled). I am using this code to handle the deletion of an item from the cart:

```
$('.delete-button').click(function(ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            idValue = $(this).parent().siblings(".name").attr('id');
            $.post("includes/delete-cart.php",{id:idValue},
            function(data){
                // Do something with returned data.
            }, "json");
            $("#wrap-change-cart").load('includes/cart-sidebar.php',function(){
                $('#loading').hide();
            }); // Load change in cart.
        });
```

The delete-cart.php file deletes the item from a database (simpled mySQL query). The issue is that when the delete button is pressed ( tag), sometimes it deletes, but sometimes it refreshes the page (as it is an a tag linked to itself), thought this should be stopped in the first 2 lines of code. Suggestions?

P.S.  Apologies about bad title

Comment: try adding $('a.delete-button') to it

Comment: Worth a shot but didn't help

Comment: hmm my second shot would be .stopImmediatePropagation() instead of .stopPropagation();

Comment: Nup :( Didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found from some further research is that as the elements are generated live (via jQuery etc), the on click events are not being added so I've switched over to using .on() which involves this code:

```
$('#wrap-change-cart').on('click', 'a.delete-button', function (ev) {
```

It now means that no page refreshes are coming though sometimes it still doesn't come through. Better than before though

Comment: So, above was half the solution. It turns out that the issue otherwise was that changing values in the database were not being received quick enough for the new values to be retaken. Aka, a delay was needed before the new values were grabbed.

Comment: Turned out that the other issue was that the database wasn't written to quickly enough before the refresh, so I added a delay

Answer (score 0):

If you have your button setup as an input tag like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
```

You can add an onclick rather than a jQuery click event handler:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return deleteCart()" name="delete" value="delete" />
```

As long as your make sure your deleteCart() function returns true the page should not reload.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, interesting thought, not getting it to work though. Seems odd if this were to work but using .stopPropagation and .preventDefault don't.

Comment: so your solution is inline js?

Comment: Yes it's not technically the most preferred method but its worked many times for me when i couldnt get jQuery to work.

Comment: Check out this example on my dev site: http://dev.briananglin.me/return_example.php